# Knockout.js observableArray vs Backbone.js Collection - What's the difference?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js

In Knockout.js I create an observableArray to push models into:

```
function Room(data) {
        this.name = ko.observable(data.name);

    }   


    function RoomViewModel() {      
        var self = this;
        self.rooms = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.newRoomText = ko.observable();         

        self.addRoom = function() {
            self.rooms.push(new Room({ name: this.newRoomText() }));
            self.newRoomText("");       
            $("#modal").dialog("close");        
        }.bind(self);           
    }
```

In Backbone.js I would create a collection to store my models:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Books = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Abe Lincoln - Vampire Hunter"}
  {name: "Pride and Prejudice and Zombies"}
]);
```

Just how different are these 2 structures from each other?

What exactly is going on behind the scenes to make these data structures different from a standard Javascript Array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a difficult question to fully answer but here is my take on it :).

[Backbone.js Collection](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection):

- fetching models from the server
- triggering change/add/remove events
- listening to model events and triggering them on collections
- automatic validation of the models
- lot of cross-browser convience methods for working with collections (each, max, sort, reduce, etc.)

[Knockout.js observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

- tracks added and removed elements - updates UI automatically
- cross-browser implementation of the array's methods (e.g. IE8 has problems w/ native `.indexOf()`)
- convience `destroy` & `destroyAll` methods for Rails developer that will set `_destroy` property on objects to `true` - this will inform Rail's ActiveRecord which objects should be deleted.

`Backbone.Collection` is working with the Backbone.js framework and `observableArray` only with Knockout.js. There is no real in comparing them with each other in a isolation because they are part of a framework and if your application is built on Backbone you cannot use `observableArray` and vice versa.

If you want to know what *exactly* is going on behind the scenes then here is the source code:

- [Backbone.Collection](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-53)
- [obervableArray](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js)

Comment: Thanks - that overview of the two is helpful.